# Does the word "facility" have a negative connotation?

Tags: meaning, nouns, connotation

When I hear about "facility" I immediately associate that with a building (like a company's headquarter, store, etc). However, some people say that it can be used to mean a "WC." Is this true? Does this word really have a negative connotation?

Comment: I am confused by your premise. *WC* doesn't have negative connotations.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/toilet-lavatory-or-loo-for-polite-society/37179#37179) with regards to euphemisms for toilet.

Comment: @Matt That question [http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/toilet-lavatory-or-loo-for-polite-society/37179#37179] does not seem to cover 'facility'.

Comment: @Kris - that wasn't my point. My point is that just because it's a euphemism for toilet doesn't mean it has negative connotations.

Comment: I've only ever heard the euphemism styled as a plural: 'Pardon me, I have to go use the facilities.' The singular doesn't have these connections.

Comment: I've heard "I need to use the facility." Although, I've never heard it used anywhere unless it was a WC or some sort of factory. It's as derogatory as calling a toilet a john.

Comment: I agree that the use of _facility_ or, more frequently, _facilities_ as a euphemism for a toilet or toilet block does not connote negativity. It is often used in other contexts (e.g., "the dining facilities" or "a sporting facility"). Perhaps you believe your audience will respond negatively to the use of _facility._ It would be helpful if you supplied the context in which you wish to use it and a sample sentence.

Answer (score 1):

*Public convenience* or *facility* could be **euphemisms** for toilets/ washrooms, not with negative connotations.

Comment: For evidence read the first paragraph of the wikipedia article for [Hotel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel) -- "with modern facilities, including en-suite bathrooms, and air conditioning or climate control." -- Not a negative connotation, but a somewhat more formal way to refer to a place's accommodations.